# Deserialize signed request in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, api, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am having difficulty deserializing a particular request type calling my Web API.

The request body (as seen by `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`):

```
--ALPHANUM_SIGNED_CHECKSUM_WITH_UNDERSCORES
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updates"; filename="update55555555555.json"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

[{"collectionType":"foods","date":"2013-11-04","ownerId":"BCD123","ownerType":"user","subscriptionId":"8675309"}]
--ALPHANUM_SIGNED_CHECKSUM_WITH_UNDERSCORES--
```

I have created a class which maps to the JSON, `List<MyModel>`, and put that in the method signature.

When calling the Web API, however, the framework generates a 415 Media Content not acceptable error message.

Is there something special I need to do to deserialize messages which have been signed like this?